# how to bind width of child element to width of parent element in silverlight

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, silverlight-4.0, width

I have a grid whose width is "1*". So the actual width decided at runtime I think.
Within that grid I have another grid whose width I want to set to the runtime width of parent grid. How Can I do that in xaml through binding.

Comment: No need to do that. A grid automatically sizes its children, including child grids. And when you say you have a Grid whose width is `1*` you certainly mean a Grid Column, don't you? You may post your XAML to make clear what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This will actually help you I guess

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=parentElementName}"
```

This binds the width to the parent element or the element name provided

Comment: What is ActualWidth property which isn't suggested by intelIsense?

Comment: Binding the width to the parent widh seems to remove the ability to be able to update the contents via `ItemsSource`. See [the strange behaviour in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136535/data-disappears-from-listview-after-assigning-new-data-to-itemssource).

Answer (score 55):

This is generic solution which may work everywhere. You wouldn't need to write parent element name. This will identify its parent and will take parent's width.

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Answer (score 28):

I think that easiest way to do same thing is:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

That is not using binding as you have been asked, but it is easier.

Comment: Much easier for my needs: put these into a grid, control widths with column definitions, HorizontalAlignment = Stretch, Profit.

Thanks.

Comment: The drawback to this seems to be that a combination of column definitions like: `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />`, <ColumnDefinition />, and  `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />` will not respect the middle column's lack of an Auto property

Comment: Worked well in a vertical stack panel in a grid cell.

Answer (score 6):

```
 Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Parent}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
```

if both controls DataContext is different.

Comment: I get "Parent is not supported in a WPF project"

Comment: Yes, Parent is not supported in WPF project, it's for silverlight. For WPF you can use actual parent control like UserControl, DataGrid and Window etc instead of Parent.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing it in CodeBehind, this works for me. It has the added advantage that bindMe does not have to be a child of toMe:

```
public static void BindWidth(this FrameworkElement bindMe, FrameworkElement toMe)
{
  Binding b = new Binding();
  b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
  b.Source = toMe.ActualWidth;
  bindMe.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, b);
}
```

usage:

```
child.BindWidth(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

HorizontalAlignment doesn't work for buttons in Xamarin, you can use HorizontalOptions instead

```xml
HorizontalOptions="Fill"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on ListBox:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="TestImage.png"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Test Text"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

or if it is inside a Template use this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="TestImage.png"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Test Text"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```