# Data disappears from ListView after assigning new data to ItemsSource

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following `ListView`:

```
<ListView 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MeditationDiary}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=ListViewHeaders, Path=ActualWidth}" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition  />
                    <ColumnDefinition  />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Text="{Binding StartTime}" />
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="{Binding TimeMeditated}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is bound to a `MeditationDiary` property of type `MeditationDiary` consisting of `MeditationEntries`:

```
public class MeditationDiary : Collection<MeditationEntry> { }

public class MeditationEntry
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeMeditated { get; set; }
}
```

The `ListView` binds to this `MeditationDiary`:

```
private MeditationDiary _meditationDiary;
public MeditationDiary MeditationDiary
{
    get
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MeditationDiary));
        return _meditationDiary;
    }
    set
    {
        _meditationDiary = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MeditationDiary));
    }
}
```

Strangely enough when I assign a new `MeditationDiary` object to the property (which contains data with `MeditationEntries`) the `ListView` does no longer display data.

I'm assigning the new `MeditationDiary` object in the `UpdateDiary` method which is called after adding an entry:

```
private async void UpdateDiary()
{
    var latestDiary = await _repository.GetAsync();
    MeditationDiary = latestDiary;
}
```

Why can this be and how can it be fixed?

Comment: @GrantWinney In the `UpdateDiary` method which is called after adding an entry:  `private async void UpdateDiary()
        {
            var latestDiary = await _repository.GetAsync();
            MeditationDiary = latestDiary;
        }` latestDiary is an object that contains entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely the culprit that's messing up your binding:

```
MeditationDiary = latestDiary;
```

Instead, try clearing out the current collection and then adding the new values to it:

```
MeditationDiary.Clear();

foreach (var entry in latestDiary)
    MeditationDiary.Add(entry);
```

You'll probably have to call `RaisePropertyChanged` on the collection after you add the new items.

As a side note, you could replace `MeditationDiary` with an `ObservableCollection<MeditationEntry>`, which automatically notifies the UI when you add/remove items in it.

Comment: Thank you Grant. This helps. I also have to remove the Binding from `Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=ListViewHeaders, Path=ActualWidth}">`. When I keep that it keeps showing the same behaviour (emptying display on update).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173892/how-to-bind-datatemplate-width-to-parent-and-be-able-to-update-viewmodel-propert).