# How to bind DataTemplate width to parent and be able to update viewmodel property?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `ListView` named `MeditationDiaryListView` with two columns and two headers. I have the width of the `DataTemplate` in the listview equal to the width of `MeditationDiaryListViewHeaders`:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid Name="MeditationDiaryListViewHeaders">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Text="Start time" 
        FontSize="16" />
    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Text="Time meditated"
        FontSize="16" />
</Grid>
<ListView 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Name="MeditationDiaryListView" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MeditationDiary}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MeditationDiaryListViewHeaders}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime}" 
                            Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeMeditated}" 
                            Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Unfortunately, when I assign new values to the property in the `ItemsSource` binding the `ListView` becomes empty. If I remove the `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MeditationDiaryListViewHeaders}` part from the `ListView` this does not happen, but then the width is not equal to the parent.

How can I both have the width equal to the parent and be able to update the contents of the `ItemsSource` of the `MeditationDiaryListView`?

Comment: What do you mean by `binding the ListView becomes empty`?  I dont think it will fix the issue, but I would set the `Grids` `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `Width` in your `DataTemplate` and set the item container width to `Stretch` on your `ListView`:

```
<ListView 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="MeditationDiaryListView" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MeditationDiary}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime}" 
                            Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeMeditated}" 
                            Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Your `ListView` and your header `Grid` should now have the same width because of their parent container.

Comment: For me, HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" works