# UWP FlipView height/vertical next button issue

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, flipview

I am trying to get a [`FlipView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/flipview) streched to the height of its parent view. The XAML look like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <FlipView x:Name="flipView" 
                      BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged" >
        <!-- Use a vertical stack panel for vertical flipping. -->
        <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
    </FlipView>

    <TextBlock x:Name="textOutput" Text="Hello"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

The children of the `FlipView` were added in C#:

```
var image1 = await MakeImageForPageIndex(1);
var image2 = await MakeImageForPageIndex(2);

flipView.Items.Add(image1);
flipView.Items.Add(image2);
```

As you can see in the screenshot the vertical next button and the bottom border are clipped.

I have tried setting `VerticalAlignment` of the `FlipView` to `Strech` with no luck. Setting the images a small `Height` didn't help either.

I have also tired `Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualHeight}"` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864831/how-to-bind-width-of-child-element-to-width-of-parent-element-in-silverlight)

Thank you all!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StackPanel` stacks its children in one direction (vertical in this case), its size grows with its children, it does not define a `bound` for its children.

Use a `Grid` to replace the `StackPanel`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <FlipView x:Name="flipView" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer. This made me wonder what does it mean to set a vertical `StackPanel`'s child's `VerticalAlignment` to `Strech`; will that make the `StackPanel` grow to infinity:p